# Multiple domains with a language each

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

We've setup that english language points to an english domain, and for spanish we have a language.

The spanish one is simply a symlink to the english code base. When translating nodes, I am being redirected to the Spanish domain when changing a spanish node, and have to login on that domain to be able to work.

How can I make sure; that either I'm logged in, or that I can stay on the same domain when editing content?

Answer (score 0):

You can't stay logged in on a different domain except you'd use some kind of single-sign-on system between your domains.

Cookies are assigned to a specific domain, the browser has no idea that he is still on the same website.

You might be able to configure separate content and interface negotation, so you stay always on your own language, or you could use the admin language feature so a certain user always stays in his language when he's on the site. But not sure if that works 100% for editing translations in Drupal 8, havent tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple domains on the same drupal 8 site, and if they share the same master domain  (en.something.mydomain.com, fr.something.mydomain.com...etc), then you can specify a value of "cookie_domain" in the file "sites/default/services.yml", like this :

```
parameters:
  session.storage.options:
    cookie_domain: '.something.mydomain.com'
```